# Esp01 Program Uploading issue

Tags: esp8266

I am trying to program ESP01 module with cp2102 USB to TTL converter, I successfully programmed it earlier

Using logic level shifter i.e. resistor divider on RX and providing 3.3 v externally

My problem is when I try to program it now with same setup that worked earlier I see as code starts uploading my ESP01 and USB to TTL module lights blink but code doesn't get uploaded.

Could it be a problem related to the baud rate? If so, what can I do to solve that?

Comment: Have you tried totally powering it off? Is the ide showing any communication errors for the com port?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to connect:

- `GPIO0` (pin #5) to `GND` (pin #1)
- `CH_EN` (pin #4 - also called `CH_PD`) to `VCC` (pin #8 - 3.3v)

[image]